# BottomNavigationView как сделать неактивными все пункты?

Tags: android, android-navigation-view

Как снять отметки со всех пунктов меню в BottonNavigationView? Получается их программно кликать, менять один выбранный на другой, но нужно снять именно со всех, а один пункт всегда остается подсвеченным.

Comment: Добавить в приложение код, который будет снимать отметки со всех пунктов меню.

Comment: Не надо добавлять тэг Android-Studio, этот вопрос туда не относится.

Comment: Вот не получается снять, bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.***).setChecked(false) не работает с BottomNavigationView. Если ставлю true - выделение переставляет на любой пункт, а false - просто никакой реакции.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode
Пробовал еще этот вариант, он у меня просто не компилируется, метода .setShiftingMode нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придется самому себе отвечать.  bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.***).setChecked(false) на все пункты меню не работает, один остается всё равно подсвеченным. Этот совет 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode
у меня тоже реализовать не получилось, метода .setShiftingMode нет. Единственное решение, которое мне удалось найти, - сделать в меню дополнительный пункт-пустышку, на него .setVisible(false) и ставить на него .setChecked(true), когда выделение нужно снять со всех. Выглядит как костыль, но лучше ничего не нашел. Буду рад, если кто-то подскажет наконец более правильный способ, вместо написания крайне "полезных" комментариев, "облегчающих" тернистый путь новичка.